# Escape PIPE character in a function call windows Batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, escaping, call, pipe

I am writing a function to execute shell commands and capture its output in a batch script.

```
:runShellCmd
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   SET lf=-
   FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('%~1') DO if "%out%" == "" (set out=%%i) else (set out=!out!%lf%%%i)
   echo "Cmd output: %out%"
   SET "funOut=%out%"
ENDLOCAL & IF "%~1" NEQ "" SET %~2=%out%
goto :EOF
```

I have been successful in passing simple commands and getting output. But for calls like

`CALL :runShellCmd "echo Jatin Kumar | find /c /i "jatin""` it fails with error `unexpected | character`.

I know we need to escape `|` with `^` in for but if I try to pass `^|` in the function argument string, it changes it to `^^|` which again throws error.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an effect of the `CALL` command.

The `CALL` command doubles all carets in one of the batch parser phases.
Normally you wouldn't see this, as the carets will be used as an escape charater directly after the doubling.

See this

```
call echo ^^^^
call call echo ^^^^
call call call echo ^^^^

call echo "^^^^"
call call echo "^^^^"
call call call echo "^^^^"
```

Output

```
^^
^^
^^
"^^^^^^^^"
"^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"
"^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"
```

But how do you can escape your pipe character?
**You can't!**

But you can add a caret remover in your function.

```
:runShellCmd
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   set "param=%~1"
   set param
   set "param=!param:^^=^!"
   for .... ('!param!')
```

Or you could use an escaping trick when calling your function.

```
set "caret=^"
CALL :runShellCmd "echo Jatin Kumar %%caret%%| find /c /i "
```

This works, as the `%%caret%%` will be expanded after the `CALL caret doubling phase`.

Comment: Precisely the problem with `^` as you mentioned. I was tying to use `%caret%` but `%%caret%%` did the trick. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion 

    call :test "echo(this|find "t""
    exit /b

:test
    set "x=%~1"
    for /f "delims=" %%f in ('%x:|=^|%') do echo [%%f]
```

I think i'm missing something, because this works for me.

EDITED - This should be a more general solution. Not bulletproof but a skeleton.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion 

    call :test "(echo(this&echo(that)|find "t" 2>nul|sort&echo end"
    exit /b

:test
    set "x=%~1"
    set "x=%x:|=^|%"
    set "x=%x:>=^>%"
    set "x=%x:<=^<%"
    set "x=%x:&=^&%"
    set "x=%x:)=^)%"
    for /f "delims=" %%f in ('%x%') do echo [%%f]
```

Comment: I am a novice to batch scripting but it looks like are replacing | by ^| in your function. I am trying to pass it in the function argument itself. I may be wrong, in that case can you please decrypt `%x:|=^|%` for me.

Comment: @jeb, yes, you are right. It is incomplete, but i was reading the question and thinking there was something i was not seeing.

Comment: @JatinKumar, Yes, you are right, it is what i'm doing. The problem is not passing the pipe, the problem is that the pipe must be escaped inside the `for /f` for it to work.